# Getting a list of filtering attributes for a CRM Plugin (already installed)

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have Dynamics CRM 4.0 installed and wrote a plugin, registered it, and setup a "step" that included a few filtering attributes.  2 questions:

1. How can I get a list of filtering attributes that are configured for my plugin? (from within the plugin itself)
2. How can I get a list of those filtering attributes that are actually on the current form being used? (also within the plugin itself)

Comment: Could you clarify this a bit? Do you mean you want to get the configuration settings for the filter? For instance plugin_x, step Create of opportunity in parent pipeline? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get every property in an image that you've sent to a plugin you can iterate through the property bag after setting it to a dynamic entity.  This will include every field on the entity.

```cs
DynamicEntity postEntity = (DynamicEntity)context.PostEntityImages["entityimage"]

foreach (Property p in postEntity.Properties)
{
    // Do something with my property
}
```

Comment: Trying this soon, not sure this will give me what I want (metadata of the plugin filtering attributes set?)

Comment: Does this give me access to the entire entity?  I'm looking for just the filtering attributes that are attached to a specific step of the plugin and only the form elements (not all entity attributes).

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question.  Are you trying to retrieve the metadata of an entity or the values that were passed into a plugin?  What do you mean by "Filtering attributes"?  I was assuming you meant the items filtered on a step image.

Comment: Filtering Attributes are chosen when you create a "step" while registering a plugin.